# methods of joining 2 tables without using JOIN or SELECT more than one distinct table in the query

Tags: sql, database, join, odbc

Is there a way of joining results from 2 tables without using JOIN or SELECT from more than one table? The reason being the database im working with requires queries that only contain SELECT, FROM, and WHERE clauses containing only one distinct table. I do, however, need information from other tables for the project i'm working on. 
More info: the querier returns the query results in a .csv format, is there something we can manipulate there?

Comment: What is your database called?

Comment: Which database are you using?  And is the restriction on the query an organizational thing or a limitation of the database?

Comment: That doesn't sound like a real database...

Comment: I guess creating a `view` is out of the question!

Comment: I think this is one of these new fancy `NoSQL` things. Now, that's why they are called so!

Answer (score 1):

Pick a programming language.  Any language will do.  Run one query, and get the results.  Run another query, get the results.  Use the programming language to combine the results.

Seriously.  You are asking how to join data from a database that doesn't support joins.  If the database doesn't support it, you're going to have to do it externally.

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.*, b.* from tablea a, tableb b
```

Comment: That's ANSI-89 join syntax - without any criteria, it's a cross join which'll produce a cartesian product.  Not downvoting, just saying.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it either by Using JOIN or SELECT. You have to use one of it. By Join you must be knowing. I am writing an example for without using JOIN and just using SELECT, to join two tables.

```
SELECT * from Table1, Table2 where Table1.common_attribute = Table2.common_attribute;
```

Comment: Is it possible to do above query using cakephp's find method without using joins ?

Comment: @binoy sorry I have no idea about cakephp. May be you can try it once if it works.